# How can i make this function working for all instances

Tags: jquery

How can i combine multiple functions into 1 general one that accomplishes the same thing.

Example HTML of inputs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fname_checkbox" id="fname_checkbox" class="fname" checked="checked" onclick="ss_checkbox()"><label for="fname_checkbox">INPUT 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="ficonname_checkbox" id="ficonname_checkbox" class="ficonname" checked="checked" onclick="ss_checkbox1()"><label for="ficonname_checkbox">INPUT 2<</label>
```

Currently i was making a function for each input , but i know that is dumb and novice , so i'd like to see how i can make a single function that does the same for all the checkboxes.

```
function ss_checkbox(){
    $('#fname_checkbox').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('.standings-filter .fname').show();
        else
            $('.standings-filter .fname').hide();
    });
}
function ss_checkbox1(){
    $('#ficonname_checkbox').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('.standings-filter .ficonname').show();
        else
            $('.standings-filter .ficonname').hide();
    });
}
```

for each input i have a ss_checkbox function to hide and show div content. How can i combine those functions and many many more like it , that will match the checkbox class name to a div class name and hide and show them.

```
<div class="fname"></div>
<div class="ficonname"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `dynamic` and more simple approach without writing alot of `code`. You need to use an [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) function **not** an `onclick` in your input and pass `this` as an `argument` which `refers` to the element which have made change on.

In your function, `ss_checkbox(e)` get this and check its [attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) which will be `class` of your `input`.

Check if the input is checked and `class` matches with any element in the `DOM` which is a `div` then we can `show` that element `else` we can `hide` that element.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function ss_checkbox(e) {
  let getClass = $(e).attr('class') //get class name
  if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
    $('div.' + getClass + '').show();
  } else {
    $('div.' + getClass + '').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="fname_checkbox" id="fname_checkbox" class="fname" checked="checked" onchange="ss_checkbox(this)"><label for="fname_checkbox">INPUT 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="ficonname_checkbox" id="ficonname_checkbox" class="ficonname" checked="checked" onchange="ss_checkbox(this)"><label for="ficonname_checkbox">INPUT 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="blah" id="blah" class="blah" checked="checked" onchange="ss_checkbox(this)"><label for="blah">INPUT 2</label>

<div class="fname">fname</div>
<div class="ficonname">ficonname</div>
<div class="blah">blah</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Your jQuery code needs to be hard coded and functions need to be duplicated because you aren’t using arguments in the wrapping function. Furthermore, “onclick” is generally not necessary when using jQuery, you can keep all of your element binding logic in JavaScript by using the .click method.

## Solution

DRY by using variables to pass in element identifiers.

```
function ss_checkbox(checkbox, filter_name){
    $(checkbox).change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $(filter_name).show();
        else
            $(filter_name).hide();
    });
}

$(“.input_field_1”).click(function() { ss_checkbox(“.checkbox”, “.filter_name”) })

$(“.input_field_2”).click(function() { ss_checkbox(“.checkbox”, “.filter_name_2”) })
```

## References

jQuery click event binding: https://api.jquery.com/click/
jQuery general event binding: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: thank you for the answer , but with no HTML changes really needed i went with other response.